# Linking Maple outputs to Latex

Tags: report, maple2e

I'm doing a report in latex on matrices and matrix exponentials and have used maple to work out some results and do some checks. I need to show these results in my report on Latex,is there anyway I can export/link my maple outputs into latex?

Comment: does this help? http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=worksheet/managing/exportLaTeX